# Programmatically add transition styles without erasing existing ones

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Suppose I'm using JS to add transition styles to a DOM element.  I may be adding transitions for several different properties from disparate pieces of code, such as `height` transitions, `background-color` transitions, and so on.

If I simply write:

```
// Location 1
el.style.transition = 'height 1s';

// Location 2
el.style.transition = 'background-color 1s';
```

then either of these transitions might override the other, if and when they are applied to the same element.

(If you'll allow me this bit of harping, it is a good thing CSS isn't a database, because this appears to be a violation of 1st normal form, as it jams structured data into a single text field, so that it's not easy to manipulate the data with regard to its structure.)

I would like to something to this effect (NOT valid):

```
// Location 1
el.style.transition.height = '1s';

// Location 2
el.style.transition.backgroundColor = '1s';
```

Which would control transitions for different properties independently of each other, if it were valid.

Question: Is it possible to add/remove transitions to/from an element for individual CSS properties, without parsing its existing `transition` string?

Would one of these work:

```
// Location 1
el.style.transition= 'height 1s, ' + el.style.transition;
```

or

```
// Location 1
el.style.transition = el.style.transition + ', height 1s';
```

So that if a `height` transition is added several times to the same element, the most recent one will be first (or last) and take precedence?  Or is it illegal to include the same property multiple times in an element's `transition` property / not specified whether the first or last occurrence is to take precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about soething like this

```
let transitionsObject = {
  height: '0.2s linear',
  width: '0.2s ease-in-out'
}

function patchTransitions(el, newOnes) {
  let old = el.style.transition.split(',');
  let news = Object.keys(newOnes).map(e => `${e} ${newOnes[e]}`);
  el.style.transition = [...old, ...news].join(',');
}
```

and remember that you can assign properties to objects even with spaces (i.e. `obj['we hate this'] = someValue`) if you don't want to parse camel case to be with spaces

```js
let transitionsObject = {
  height: '0.2s linear',
  width: '0.2s ease-in-out'
}

function patchTransitions(el, newOnes) {
  let old = el.style.transition.split(',');
  let news = Object.keys(newOnes).map(e => `${e} ${newOnes[e]}`);
  el.style.transition = [...old, ...news].join(',');
}

let el = document.getElementById('mario');
el.style.transition = 'width 0.2s linear';

setInterval(() => {
  el.style.width = el.style.width == '400px' ? '200px' : '400px';
  el.style.height = el.style.height == '400px' ? '200px' : '400px';
}, 1000);

document.getElementById('patch').onclick = () => {
  let trans = {
    height: '0.2s ease-in-out',
  };
  patchTransitions(el, trans);
}
```

```css
#mario {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="patch">click me</button>
<div id="mario">watch me</div>
```